# Ingresar todos los parámetros de un método en un array automáticamente en Java

Tags: java

Me he encontrado con un **proyecto** que pasa un gran cantidad de **parámetros** a mi **método**, y por **especificación** no puedo cambiar la forma en la que invocan a mi **método**.

Lo que necesito es poder ingresar todos los **parámetros** que me pasan en un **array** (o lista) para tratarlos en un **método** auxiliar propio. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de relizar esto automáticamente o recorrer los **parámetros** para ingresarlos manualmente usando un bucle y los **índices** de dicho **parámetro**, en vez de tener que ingresarlos "a mano" nombrándolos. Algo así:

```
public String metodo (String param1, String param2, String param3, ...) {
List <String> parámetros = new List <String>();
//RECORRER LOS PARÁMETROS INCLUYENDOLOS EN MI LISTA
metodoAuxiliar(parámetros);
...
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 6):

Java tiene desde hace mucho (desde Java 5), la opción de definir métodos con un número indeterminado de parámetros:

```
class MiClase {

  void metodo(String ... params) {
     //params es un array de Strings, es equivalente a String[] params
     if (params.length>0) { //params puede ser vacío, como explico más adelante
        for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
           String param=params[i]; //puede ser null
        }
     } else {
       //se ha llamado al método sin ningún parámetro
     }
  }
}
```

Limitaciones de esta declaración:

- Todos los parámetros serán del mismo tipo (puedes usar Object, claro, pero es engorroso).
- Los parámetros definidos con ... siempre serán los últimos del método:

  ```
  void metodo(String... params, int otro); //no compila

  void metodo(String...params, Integer... numeros) //no compila
  ```

Posibles formas de llamar a un método void metodo(MiClase... params):

```
miObj.metodo() // Sin parámetros, params será un array con cero elementos

miObj.metodo( p1, p2) //Añadiendo cada parámetro individualmente
MiClase [] array;
miObj.metodo(array); //directamente con un array
```

Como curiosidad, esto ahora es una forma válida (y equivalente) de crear el método main de una aplicación:

```
class MiClase {
    public static void main(String... args) {

    }
}
```

**Actualización:** El usuario @Klaimmore correctamente comenta que el OP no puede modificar la firma porque se rompería la retrocompatibilidad, pero esta solución permite modificarla manteniendo dicha compatibilidad: cualquier código que llama a metodo(p1,p2,p3,...pN), seguiría compilando con la nueva firma. De todos modos se puede implementar esta solución de este otro modo:

```
public String metodo (String param1, String param2, String param3, ...) {
    metodoAuxiliar(param1,param2,param3,...);
    ...
}

private void metodoAuxiliar(String params...) {
    ... //aquí ya tienes un array
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no soluciona la pregunta. ¿Puedes explicar cómo tratarías esos parámetros sin nombrarlos para acceder a ellos?

Comment: @pablo Estaba "under construction", como la respueta iba a ser larga primero puse un "boceto" para que el OP pudiese empezar a mirar el cocepto. Ya está listo

Comment: A mi juicio sigue sin solucionar la pregunta. Requiere posiblemente modificar la firma del metodo que es lo que el OP dijo no podía hacer.

Comment: @Klaimmore Tienes razón, pero si el motivo es la retrocompatibilidad, en realidad el OP **sí** puede cambiar la firma. De todos modos edito para dar soluciones a eso.